# FQL WHERE IN with Null feedback in the array

Tags: facebook-fql

I'm trying the command below:

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field IN(1,2,3, NULL, 5)
and the result is {r1,r2,r3}
I want {r1,r2,r3,NULL,r4}, how can I do that?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm actually trying to get creator name and picture from my events. However, some events has creator as "NULL", which terminated my query... SELECT id, name, pic FROM profile WHERE id in (SELECT creator FROM event WHERE eid in (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me()))

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Facebook automatically filters out NULL results from the rows. There is also no guarantee that the results will be in the same order as the arguments you passed in your `IN` criteria.

You also can't `SELECT *` in FQL. You have to individually select fields to return.

You'll need to do something like this:

```
  THINGS_TO_FIND = array (1,2,3,NULL,5)
  RESULT = FQL_URL + urlencode('SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE field1 IN ' + THINGS_TO_FIND')
   foreach (THING in THINGS_TO_FIND) {
      foreach (ITEM in RESULT) {
         if THING == ITEM->field1 then OUTPUT->field1 = ITEM->field2
      }
   }
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to get creator name and picture from my events.  However, some events has creator as "NULL", which terminated my query...


SELECT id, name, pic FROM profile WHERE id in (SELECT creator FROM event WHERE eid in (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me()))

Comment: You need to use a multiquery then: `{"my_events":"SELECT eid, creator FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid=me())", "event_creators":"SELECT id, name, pic FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT creator FROM #my_events)"}`